# Finding the image of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Find the image of this linear transformation: $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=(x_1+x_2-x_3, x_1-x_2-x_3, x_1+x_2+x_3,x_2-x_3)$$

My very first thought was just to do the simple algebraic move: $$(x_1+x_2-x_3, x_1-x_2-x_3, x_1+x_2+x_3,x_2-x_3)=x_1(1,1,1,0)+x_2(1,-1,1,1)+x_3(-1,1,1,0)$$ So then we have that $\text{Im} f=\text{span}\{(1,1,1,0),(1,-1,1,1), (-1,1,1,0)\}$. But the book tries to solve the system formed by an arbitrary variable $y=(y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4)$ and does Gaussian simplification of the matrix equation $y=Fx$, being $F$ the matrix that represents the transformation, and they get to another whole different image, is that the way to go? Or mine is as well correct but there can be different images for the same linear transformation?

Comment: Your answer is correct. If you want a *basis* for the image, then you need to make sure the vectors in your set are *linearly independent*. Without further information, it seems like that is what the textbook solution is trying to do.

Comment: @K.Jiang my bad, it does ask the *basis* of the image, does that change the veridity of my solution? I think my solution is still linearly independent

Comment: Are you saying that the book gave constraint equations that $y$ must satisfy? These are the two viewpoints — equations for a subspace versus spanning vectors for the subspace. Oh, they want a basis. So I don’t understand what you say they are actually doing.

Comment: @TedShifrin but on any case, if my solution is linearly independent, it can be a valid solution for the basis for the image, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct.

The solution can have different ways to present, and they are all equivalent. Let's see a simple example, suppose $f(x_1, x_2)=(x_1, x_2)$, then

$$\text{Im}f=\text{span}\{(1,0), (0,1)\}=\mathbb R^2$$

but you can also write it as

$$\text{Im}f=\text{span}\{(1,1), (0,1)\}=\text{span}\{(e,\sqrt2), (-1,\pi)\}=\dots$$

Namely, as long as the solution spans  $\mathbb R^2$, they are all correct.